# Android studio emulator skin with M1 Pro

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, android-emulator, apple-m1

Hey guys so I am trying to set up my 16 inch MacBook pro M1 pro for react native app development. While setting android studio I tried to set the android studio emulator with skin but it does not work. I tried searching the web but didn't find much information and as far as I have seen Youtube most of them also have the same. I tried the advanced settings and tried to set the skin option but it still doesn't work I'm just asking is it my set up or it's with everyone

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue with Android Studio's Emulator on my 2020 M1 Macbook. I tried many different devices and android versions but it seems that Android skins/ frames/ camera cut outs are unsupported on the new silicon chips: https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/my-journey-to-setup-android-emulator-for-m1-macbook-pro-b8365321b3e7

However, I found a workaround that will get you a punch-hole camera and a couple of different options that might suit your needs. This can be achieved by:

1. Go into the phone settings app (the emulated device settings, within the emulator itself)
2. Find the build number (usually under "About emulated device")
3. Click on the build number 7+ times (this activates developer options)
4. Go into the developer options and find "device cut out"- here there will be several options such as a punch hole camera which will make the AVD emulate a suitable cut out within the device screen. This will at least allow you to test to see if your status bar is responsive to such things.

[Screenshot of AVD Google Pixel 5 API 33 with punch hole camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgEUs.png)

Hope this helps and please let me know if you find another way.